# upload file should accepts XLS files only file size limit 5mb Angular 13

Tags: javascript, angular, angular9, angular12

I need do upload file which accepts XLS files only file size limit 5mb Angular 13?

**HTML**

> `<input name="file" type="file" (change)="onSelectFile($event)" required/> <button type ="file"> </button>`

**Ts file**

```
onSelectFile(event:any){
const allowed_type = ['application/xslx']
if (this.file.size >5000 * 1024 && this.files.type !== allowed_type) {
this.warning = true;     
 } else {
 this.warning = false; 
   }
}
```

here I can only get warning msg on size limit not file type

I need both the validations happen.

also tried in this way:

```
 if (this.file.size >5000 * 1024) {
    this.warning = true;     
     } else if (this.files.type !== allowed_type){
     this.warning = true; 
    }else{
this.warning = false;
}
```

Here I should not allow more 5mb and file type should accept only xsl format.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234589/validation-of-file-extension-before-uploading-file) for file type and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33598129/how-to-check-maximum-upload-file-size-in-javascript-validation) for file size

Comment: not sure file extension for xlsx, but  change like this `const allowed_type = ['.xlsx']`

Comment: @Pterrat I should accepts only .xls files and file size should be 5mb. please suggest how to make it possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to upload a particular file format just add **accept** tag over there in the input tab.

```
<input name="file" type="file" (change)="onSelectFile($event)" accept=".xls" required/>
```

in .ts file you can check for the selected file is .xls or not by using

```
if (fileObj.type == "application/xls")
```